# Accessing dictionary values that are lists of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

How would I refer to a value inside of a list inside of a list that is the value of a particular term in a dictionary?

```
{value: [[1,2], []]}
```

How would I refer to the 1 in the example above to, for example += it?

Comment: Would you be able to do it if you just had a plain list of lists? Well, assuming a name of `mydict` for the dict, `mydict['value']` is the name of the contained list of lists, so proceed accordingly.

Comment: I took a liberty to edit [1,] to [1,2] because the first is equivalent to [1].

Comment: Thank you, that does help clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like to any other list element:

```
mydict['value'][0][0]
```

---

Think about it iteratively:

`mydict['value']` is `[[1,2], []]`

To access the first element of that list you have:

`mydict['value'][0]` is `[1,2]`

Finally, the first element of your final list:

`mydict['value'][0][0]` is `1`

Comment: Thank you, this is what I am looking for. I was unable to locate anywhere on these forums or the documentation how to refer to the value of a specific key of a dictionary in this context which is the reason for the simple question. Perhaps just a small explanation on that would be good for the community.

Comment: I have realized that I have an issue with doing this because there isn't already a value stored there. How do I create a value in this same manner?

Comment: @cbbcbail Same as for any other list. `mydict['value'][0] = []` to initialize, `mydict['value'][0].append(1)` to append value of 1 to the list.

Comment: Sorry, I kept getting an out of index error which I have now resolved. Thanks for your help!